# Having trouble with Happytime.C

Tags: windows, virus

On last Saturday evening, stupidly downloading a file with Internet explorer as I wasn't managing to do so with Chrome, I received a virus named **Happytime.C** : it started telling "We've got your facebook information, Credit cards login" blablabla ...
I switched off my computer, unplugging it from current and Internet. As I restarted it, it stopped booting on what I refer as the "how do I boot now ?" page - basically a black screen with just a dash, page that appears just after the bios normal message. - I shut it down a second time: at that point I freaked out.
Twenty minutes later, I switched it on back again, and everything seemed normal.

I run a virus analysis using Avira, - nothing was detected - and a complete analysis of all my hard drives using windows defender, and it somehow detected (to my surprise) something. Here it is : [image]

Since then, no problem, but here are my questions:

1. Can this virus propagate to other computer/phones linked to my internet box via Wifi/RJ45 ?
2. Now that windows defender has "erased" (I know it's not as simple as that unfortunately), is there still a danger using my version of windows ?
3. Can the virus operate not now but in the future, even if it is "erased" ?
4. Should I change all my password knowing they are all unique and at least 15 characters long ? (including special ones)

Thank you a lot in advance for your responses.

PS: Moreover, yesterday my internet box stopped working for 20 minutes, and chrome was announcing me a corrupted certificate issue; could it be somehow related ?

Comment: I've linked to the canonical answer for all home PC virus infections, but in short: 1. Don't know, but it could probably bootstrap something that could. 2. Yes, still a danger. 3. Possibly. 4. Depends - if you used them on that machine since infection, probably not a bad idea. If they were in a text file in your Documents folder, yes. If you remember them all, or they're in an encrypted file for a password manager app, they're probably fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! All my passwords are in my mind basically. I used to have only one of them on my phone but now they are all in my memory. Is that virus known ? I'm impressed there is not much about it on the internet ... Furthermore, do you know if some offline antivirus boot analysis could be an efficient option, rather than reinstalling windows from scratch ?

Comment: In theory analysis would be fine, but you'd need to be a specialist to do it, and even then, it would only usually be used when there is a really pressing need not to reinstall immediately (e.g. critical infrastructure during emergency). Even then, it's a temporary measure - you can't be 100% sure of what that machine is doing.